# How to connect application with internal IP on browser on GCP

Tags: google-compute-engine

Currently I have deployed sample spring code on GCE and started the application. I am unable to access application with internal IP. For security purpose, I need to use connect application with internal IP not with external IP. can you please help me on this?

Comment: Have a look at the documentation [Securely connecting to VM instances](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/connecting-securely).  As a possible workaround, you can use SSH tunnel, SOCKS or use `curl` command to check your application from Cloud Shell, also you can create yet another VM in the same VPC and check your application from it. Please let me know if it acceptable for you?

Comment: Have you solved your issue?